# Which settings are saved under the .idea folder and which are not?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I am confused about which settings are saved into the .idea project folder and which are not.

For example, if I add some File Watchers to the project, I know those are saved into the .idea folder. But if I enable/disable certain plugins, where is that setup saved? Into the project's .idea folder or into the whole IDE?

The goal is to keep more control of what is going on, because when working on the same project with multiple people I get confused with the .idea folder being constantly modified (and affecting my workflow).

JetBrains recommends to keep the .idea folder in the version control system, and I see some good points in that, but I want to be aware of which settings are saved under the .idea folder and which are not?

Comment: see: [What is the .idea folder?](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-), on the support webpages of this product.

Comment: `.idea` contains setting for THIS PROJECT. The IDE-wide settings (like plugins) are stored in the global folder: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html. **Keep in mind** that certain settings can be project-specific and IDE-wide (like File Watchers, Deployment entry, Language Injection Rule etc). Also see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839